# Condition of Shimura correspondence

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

(Sorry for my poor english.)

Let $N$ be an integer and $t$ be a square-free integer. Let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character modulo $4N$. 
In [Shimura's paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1970831.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Acbab753b40dc4ac59d4769418e2b5a4b), Shimura defined 'Shimura correspondence',
\begin{equation}
S_{k+\frac{1}{2}}(\Gamma_0(4N),\chi)\to M_{2k}(\Gamma_0(2N),\chi^2).
\end{equation}
In his main theorem, assume that "$f$ is a Hecke eigenform of $T(p^2)$ for prime factor $p$ of $N$ not dividing the conductor of $\chi_t$."

However, in Ono's book, "The Web of Modularity: Arithmetic of the Coefficients of Modular Forms and $q$-series", this condition does not exist. (For all $f\in S_{k+\frac{1}{2}}(\Gamma_0(4N),\chi)$...without hecke eigenform)

Which is right? Do I need Hecke eigenform condition for Shimura correspondence?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: They are both finite-dimensional vector spaces, so you can write an cusp form in terms of a basis of eigenforms.